# How can we implement search functionality on the encrypted data in mongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, encryption, hipaa

I have used the **mongoose-field-encryption** package which allows me to encrypt and decrypt the data before storing and accessing it. But I need to implement search functionality for the encrypted fields directly in the query itself.

The fields are email id, name, mobile number, address, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate query's `$function` feature to decrypt data within the query and apply filters. Explore `$function` [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/). Something like

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
    addFields: {
      decryptedEmail: {
        {
          $function: {
          body: function decrypt(email){ ... },
          args: ["$emailColumnName"],
          lang: "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { decryptedEmail: emailToMatch }
  }
])
```

what it does is, create a new field named `decryptedEmail` and the value of it is being computed by a decrypt function, and then we are filtering out the email we want

Comment: Can you please show me some examples of how to use it for decryption? I am not able to find proper solutions so.

Thanks

Comment: First, if you're not fimiliar with aggregation and how it works [explore here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html). Then, with a `$function` pipeline, you can simply write a js function which would take arguments from query, decrypt them and return back to query, and then you can use another pipeline after it for your filters (most likely `$match` pipeline)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I am familiar with aggregation functions and their pipeline. I am not familiar with `$function` pipeline.

Here is the implementation I have done using `$function` in aggregation
`{ $addFields: { decryptedValue: { $function: { body: function(email){return fieldEncryption.decrypt(email, process.env.SECRET_KEY);}, args: ["$email"], lang: "js" }}}},`
fieldEncryption => **mongoose-field-encryption**.

Comment: But I am getting the error `PlanExecutor error during aggregation:: caused by:: ReferenceError: fieldEncryption is not defined` while executing it.

Comment: make sure the mongodb version you're using is min 4.4

Comment: Yes, I am using mongoDB above 5.0 version

Comment: great. Make sure if `fieldEncryption` service being injected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245811/discussion-between-harshal-faldu-and-usama-masood).